# How to give a instance a function from a library in C?

Tags: c++

I wanted to give the aRest library 
a function to expose to the api.
But I am importing a customlibrary,
I wanted to give the aRest instance a function in that library.
This is my code

```
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <aREST.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>


//My Custom Made C/C++ Libraries
#include <DeviceEeprom.h>
#include <DeviceRoute.h>

//Creating my customLib instances
DeviceEeprom deviceEeprom   = DeviceEeprom();
DeviceRoute deviceRoute     = DeviceRoute();

// Create aREST instance
aREST rest = aREST();

int myFunction();


void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(115200);
 rest.set_id("1");
 rest.set_name("esp8266");
 rest.function("myFunction" &myFunction);
}

void loop()
{

}

int myFunction()
{
 return 1;
}
```

I wanted to go from this.

`rest.set_function("myFunction" &myFunction);`

To this.

`rest.set_function("myFunction" deviceRoute.myFunction());`

UPDATE

I found the rest.function() code
This is the code

```
void function(char * function_name, int (*f)(String)){

  functions_names[functions_index] = function_name;
  functions[functions_index] = f;
  functions_index++;
}
```

Mayby this helps out?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be public documentation for aRest that I can find.  How to approach this depends on what the type `aRest::set_function` expects for its second parameter.  You will either need a static or freestanding wrapper function or you will need to use a `this`-capturing lambda or similar.  Depends if `set_function` wants a C-style function pointer or a C++-style functor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to pass a pointer to a non-static member function directly to `aREST::function`.

Non-static member functions are different than static member functions and freestanding functions.  They require an object to work on.  That means that `&DeviceRoute::myFunction` is not compatible with the type `int(*)(String)`.  Instead it's a `int (DeviceRoute::*)(String)`.

To make this work, you need a static or freestanding wrapper function that calls the member function you want.  Since `aREST::function` doesn't accept any sort of context pointer, your only real option is to use a global variable:

```
//Creating my customLib instances
DeviceEeprom deviceEeprom;
DeviceRoute deviceRoute;

// Create aREST instance
aREST rest;

int myFunction(String s)
{
    return deviceRoute.myFunction(s);
}

void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(115200);
 rest.set_id("1");
 rest.set_name("esp8266");
 rest.function("myFunction" &myFunction);
}

void loop()
{

}
```